# Default user Postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I'm quite new to PostgreSQL and I'm following a #Udacity course to learn about it.

In the course is mentioned that the default Postgres user is "postgres" so I only need to use the following line to create a DB from the terminal, in order to create a "sample_database_1" database:

```
createdb sample_database_1
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
createdb: error: no se pudo conectar a la base de datos template1: FATAL:
no existe el rol «jvillarroel»
```

which means that the user "jvillarroel" (which is the same as my Windows 10 admin session) doesn't exist.

So:

- How do I change the default user to be "postgres"?
- What am I doing wrong here?
- Is some configuration the installation?

Any tip of advice will be very well received.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

My spanish is a bit rough but it seems as though your connection to the database is the issue

`o se pudo conectar a la base de datos template1` = Cant connect to template1  ?

I would guess that you are attempting to connect to the DB using windows authentication and the DB is not configured to handle these requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you mentioned, is exactly what It says. But I don't get why it is attempting to connect to the template1 database?

Comment: Its probably your connection string if you have anything like this 'postgresql://my-server.com:5432/template_1' then you will be attempting to connect to the server with 0 authentication and using the template_1 db. 

What does your conn string look like?

EDIT: You should add it to the question btw just to clear everything up.

Comment: Sorry my inexpertise :S How do I get the connection string?

Comment: Depends what software are you using to get here, psql?